# What is difference between Mercedes C (W203) C180, C200, C230 1800 cm3 engines?

Tags: engine, mercedes-benz

What is difference between Mercedes W203

- M271E20 (C180)
- M271E18ML (C200)
- M271E18ML (C230)

engines?

Is there any mechanical difference between this engines?

Comment: At which level ? Pistons, connecting rods and crank or for the ancilliaries or for engine mounts or for the output / performance?

Comment: I see that there is a difference in performance. It seems to me that ECU software is the only difference, but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you looking at pure engine performance figures ie power and torque at the flywheel or are you looking at the quoted times and power for the cars themselves? If it is data based on each version of the car then the figures will be different due to weight, gearing etc

Comment: No, Im looking for mechanical difference like pistons, kompressor,  connecting rods etc.

Comment: So, where exactly do you get figures showing a difference in performance?